# Extract values from a long string

Tags: ruby, string

I struggle to extract the ID and Answer values from a string sent from an iOS app. In the following example, I have four IDs and four Answers that need to be extracted.

```
s = "ID:1_Answer1_ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5"

IDs_array = [1,2,3,789]
Answers_array = [Answer1,Answer2,AnswerRandom,Answer3.5]
```

Appreciate any helps or suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ids, answers = s.scan(/ID:(\d+)_([^_]+)/).transpose
```

The idea of the regex is:

1. *Ids* are preceded by *ID:* - `ID:`
2. The actual *ids* are numbers - `(\d+)`
3. They are separated from the *answers* with underscore - `_`
4. The *answers* themselves are a sequence of non-underscore characters `([^_]+)`

`String#scan` with return array of pair arrays `[id, answer]`, therefore we transpose it to get two arrays - one with *ids* and one with *answers*. Then we use multiple assignment which will unpack the outer array.

Comment: Very clean solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: However it doesn't capture a blank answer value. For example, question 1 doesn't have any answer.
s = "ID:1__ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5"

Comment: @rak, you can replace `+` with `*` if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, my proposition:

```
i = 0
names = []
ids = []
s = "ID:1_Answer1_ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5"

s.split("_").each do |f|
    if i.odd?
        names.push(f)
    else
        ids.push(f.split(":")[1])       
    end
    i+=1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing it. Here's one that uses two successive `split`'s and no regex. I've assumed the string begins `ID:`, as further specification of the problem would be required if that were not necessarily the case.

```
ids, answers = s[3..-1].split(/_ID:/).map { |str| str.split('_') }.transpose
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "789"],
  #    ["Answer1", "Answer2", "AnswerRandom", "Answer3.5"]]
```

The steps:

```
t = s[3..-1]
  #=> "1_Answer1_ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5" 
a = t.split('_ID:')
  #=> ["1_Answer1", "2_Answer2", "3_AnswerRandom", "789_Answer3.5"] 
b = a.map { |str| str.split('_') }
  #=> [["1", "Answer1"], ["2", "Answer2"],
  #    ["3", "AnswerRandom"], ["789", "Answer3.5"]] 
b.transpose
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "789"],
  #    ["Answer1", "Answer2", "AnswerRandom", "Answer3.5"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please clarify your question.

Do ID's and answers need to match? are they always in pairs? Is the `"_"` character always used as a separator (this means that answers should be encoded)? Is the format always:

`"ID:#{id_mumber}_#{answer in text}"`   ... `"_"` ... *

I will assume the answer to all the questions I asked is "Yes", but if I'm wrong, please edit your question and leave me a comment - I'll edit the answer.

```
s = "ID:1_Answer1_ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5"

answer_hash = {}

tmp = s.split('_')

answer_hash[tmp.shift[3..-1].to_i] = tmp.shift while tmp[0]

answer_hash # => {1=>"Answer1", 2=>"Answer2", 3=>"AnswerRandom", 789=>"Answer3.5"} 
answer_hash.keys # => [1, 2, 3, 789]
answer_hash.values # => ["Answer1", "Answer2", "AnswerRandom", "Answer3.5"]
```

**EDIT**

I loved @ndn's answer using a Regexp... It's clearer, but might be slower for shorter strings.

Here are the benchmarks on my machine - They show that the difference in performance is mainly for shorter ID strings:

```
s = "ID:1_Answer1_ID:2_Answer2_ID:3_AnswerRandom_ID:789_Answer3.5"

puts Benchmark.measure {100_000.times {answer_hash = {}; tmp = s.split('_'); answer_hash[tmp.shift[3..-1].to_i] = tmp.shift while tmp[0] } }

# ### Short string using str
# =>   0.280000   0.000000   0.280000 (  0.286917)

puts Benchmark.measure {100_000.times {ids, answers = *s.scan(/(?<=ID:)(\d+)_([^_]+)/).transpose } }

# ### Short string using string.scan Regexp
# =>  0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.595052)



s = []
100.times {|i| s << ("ID:#{i}_Answer#{i}") }
s = s.join('_')



puts Benchmark.measure {100_000.times {answer_hash = {}; tmp = s.split('_'); answer_hash[tmp.shift[3..-1].to_i] = tmp.shift while tmp[0] } }

# ### Medium string using string.split
# =>  7.180000   0.010000   7.190000 (  7.213266)


puts Benchmark.measure {100_000.times {ids, answers = *s.scan(/(?<=ID:)(\d+)_([^_]+)/).transpose } }

# ### Medium string using string.scan Regexp
# =>  8.860000   0.020000   8.880000 (  8.888352)



s = []
1000.times {|i| s << ("ID:#{i}_Answer#{i}") }
s = s.join('_')


puts Benchmark.measure {1000.times {answer_hash = {}; tmp = s.split('_'); answer_hash[tmp.shift[3..-1].to_i] = tmp.shift while tmp[0] } }

# ### Long string using string.split (shorter benchmark)
# =>  0.690000   0.000000   0.690000 (  0.693698)


puts Benchmark.measure {1000.times {ids, answers = *s.scan(/(?<=ID:)(\d+)_([^_]+)/).transpose } }

# ### Long string using string.scan Regexp (shorter benchmark)
# =>  0.900000   0.000000   0.900000 (  0.901358)
```

Comment: lol... Regexes aren't inherently slower. They are slow when you do a lot of backtracking. Here there will be no backtracking whatsoever, because `ID:` and `_` set clear boundaries on where *ids* and *answers* start and end. As you could see in the benchmarks with bigger input, there is nothing asymptotically different between the regex and non-regex solutions. It is just that the constant operations in the regex solution need a little more prep time. You shouldn't let micro optimizations run your code. Also OP said he is dealing with a *"long string"*.

Comment: @ndn - Good to know :-)    ... I guess you're right. I usually let micro optimizations run my code only when the code is about to run over and over again inside loops (such as when it's part of a parsing engine  that's used often). If the code isn't repeated as often, I usually opt for the clearer code. Machines are getting stronger and 'faster code' does not always mean 'better code' anymore.

Comment: Also I updated my regex, since it didn't really need a lookbehind for the `ID:` part and removed the manual unpacking. I believe the benchmarks for the short string on your machine should give you somewhere around **0.470000** now.